# Select a parent whose first child is a certain tag

Tags: xml, xpath

how can i select the second `<son>`. it should be something like this: `parent[first-child='son']`

```
<parent>
   <daughter>
   <son>
</parent>
<parent>
   <son>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a son which is not preceded by anything:

```
//son[not(preceding-sibling::*)]
```

If the parent needs to be specified, use

```
//son[not(preceding-sibling::*)][parent::parent]
```

(Note that the first `parent::` means the axis, while the second `parent` is the name of the element.)

Comment: Does `preceding-sibling::*` return `false` when there will be no selection by the that `Axis` ? I am new thus asking the same..

Comment: @Babai: It returns an empty node list.

Comment: *+1* first...Okay,so when an empty nodeset is passed as an argument to `not()`,it is treated as `false` ..right ?

Comment: @Babai: As you can see.

Comment: humm..got some taste from here [**`Remarks`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256159.aspx).

Comment: @Babai: No way, sorry.

Comment: Ok,no issue,,I will then ask here in the comment box...:)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `//parent[*[1][local-name() = 'son']]`. That selects the `parent` element where the first element child node has the local name `son`.

Comment: can be written as `//parent[*[1][self::son]]`.. :) anyway *+1*.